# My login page does not seem to work at all

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Login Page. I am sure that the database is connected, but when I submit the form, the page refreshes and nothing happens.
May I please know what's wrong here? I cant seem to fix it. =(

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('common/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: adminhomepage.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }

}
?>
```

Here is my form.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>
        XXX
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>
<body>
<img id= "loginlogo" src="images/loginlogo.png" alt="XXX">
<h1 id = "loginmain">
    XXX
</h1>
<br>
    <div id= "inputs">
        <form id ="loginform" action="login.php" method="post">
            <h2 id = "loginheading">
                LOGIN
            </h2>
            <hr id ="loginline">
                        <br>
                <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>
                        <br><br>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <br><br>
                <input id="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you echo the $count and see what it is coming?

Comment: Check also for password and add an `exit();` after calling header

Comment: Check on html if form has method equals post method="post"

Comment: try to add an else to the if(isset(...)) and echo in every section. I suspect the query may not work. so echo $result and echo die(....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set names on your HTML input (username/password). You have only set an ID (ID is used for assigning CSS). Please add `name='username'` and `name='password'` to your input. By doing so,  `$_POST[username]` and `$_POST[password]` will now contain the values posted in your form.

Ergo, your current code says: If `$_POST[username]` is set, do this. And if it is not set, nothing happens (ergo the blank page). Try adding this after your last } before making my suggested changes:

`else {
echo "SESSION[username] is not set";
}`

Im guessing this will give you the message "SESSION[username] is not set" instead of a blank page?

Comment: I got this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 27

Comment: Please add quotes around $_POST keys, because php recognize them as a constant this way.

Answer (score 2):

When debugging, it is sometimes useful to print the received values for $username and $password using echo(). Maybe you will find that one of the POST[] elements is not being sent properly. Posting login form would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are some important changes what you need to know:

- Do not use mysql functions, use mysqli or PDO instead, bacuase mysql functions are deprecated.
- Always avoid about sql injections! Escape your strings, they are came from a form.
- You do not need to create `$username` and `$password` variable, if you do not use them later or do not want to manipulate them. Simply use the `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]` directly.
- Do not store clear text passwords in your database. Use a crypt algorithm like md5, and compare the value of your table with the crypted password.

You can also try to debug your code, before you redirect your page. So when you are debug, comment out the `header("Location ...");` line, and dump your sql.

So your code should seems like this, when you debugging:

```
session_start();
require_once('common/config.php');
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["username"]). "'"
        . " AND password='".md5($_POST["password"]). "'";
    echo $sql; //Here you can see, what your $sql has, and you can paste it directly into your CLI or phpMyAdmin, etc...
    $result = mysql_queryi($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];
        header("location: adminhomepage.php");
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Still no change. =( Maybe something is wrong with my form?